# What is a proper response to "What's up"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, idiomatic-language

I am wondering what a proper response to "What's up" can be. In the following example, we have "Your time, Cage" as in you will die, but I am not sure how this can be a proper response, to "What's up" as in "How are you?"

> What's up, Frosty the Snow Chick?
>
> Your time, Cage.
>
> Clever girl.

Is there something I am missing here? The second line doesn't seem to make sense as a response given it's in response to the first line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Your time is up" is a common idiomatic phrase for telling someone they are about to die.  The response by Frosty the Snow Chick is snarky and takes the inquiry somewhat literally.

A proper response to the question can vary from:

> Nothing much. (i.e., I have nothing going in my life that's notable.)

or

> I'm doing/going/seeing X Y today or this weekend.

"What's up" could also be used as a response to another statement or question:

> Student: I have an issue with the course.
>
> Professor: What's up?

Comment: So basically she was saying "His time is what's up"?

Comment: Exactly.  It's a bit of a play on words, albeit one that's kind of a cliche.